# How can I stop the infinite loop in my React supabase Authentication?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, supabase

I have two files a "Home" and a "LoginPage". The defined routes are that "/" goes to LoginPage and "/home" goes to Home. When I try to login using the Auth component from supabase Auth Ui React, I end up in an infinite loop.

I have tried adding some other logic to the else if statement in LoginPage and I've played around with adding dependencies to the useEffect but I am having no luck in stopping the infinite loop. I would like it so that when the user logs in it displays the Home component, and when the user uses the sign out button on Home the Auth login is displayed.

`HomePage`

```js
    import { ResponsiveAppBar } from "../ResponsiveAppBar";
    import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
    import { Button } from '@mui/material';
    import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js';
    import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    import UserContext from '../Contexts/UserContext';

    export function Home() {
      const supabaseUrl = 'SUPABASE_URL';
      const supabaseKey = import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_APP_SUPABASE_KEY;
      const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseKey);
      const navigate = useNavigate();
      const [user, setUser] = useContext(UserContext);

      useEffect(() => {
        async function getUserData() {
          await supabase.auth.getUser().then((value) => {
            // value.data.user
            if (value.data?.user) {
              console.log(value.data.user);
              setUser(value.data.user);
            }
          });
        }
        getUserData();
      }, []);

      const signOutUser = async () => {
        console.log("sign out clicked");
        await supabase.auth.signOut();
        navigate("/");
      };

      return (
        <>
          <ResponsiveAppBar />
          <h1>Feed</h1>
          <Button variant="contained" onClick={signOutUser}>Sign Out</Button>
        </>
      );
    }
```

`LoginPage`

```js
    import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js';
    import { Auth } from '@supabase/auth-ui-react';
    import { ThemeSupa } from '@supabase/auth-ui-shared';
    import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

    export function LoginPage() {
      const supabaseUrl = 'SUPABASE_URL';
      const supabaseKey = import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_APP_SUPABASE_KEY;
      const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseKey);
      const navigate = useNavigate();

      useEffect(() => {
        supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange(async (event) => {
          if (event === "SIGNED_IN") {
            console.log("entered signed in");
            navigate("/home");
          } else if (event !== "SIGNED_IN") {
            console.log("entered signed out");
            navigate("/");
          }
        });
      }, []);

      return (
        <div className='login'>
          {/* <center>
            <h1>SocialFitness</h1>
          </center> */}
          <Auth
            supabaseClient={supabase}
            appearance={{ theme: ThemeSupa }}
            theme="dark"
            providers={['facebook', 'google']}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to redirect the user to the login page if they are already at the login page. I would simplify your `onAuthStateChange` callback like this.

```js
supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange(async (event) => {
  if (event === "SIGNED_IN") {
    console.log("entered signed in");
    navigate("/home");
  }
});
```