# NextJS 13, Stuck in infinite GET request loop when using Next-Auth middleware. Failed to fetch RSC payload

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, jwt, next-auth

## SOLVED!!:

Turns out using the beta turbopack causes this bug to happen. I have opened an issue we'll see when they resolve this.

## Question:

I recently started working on a project in NextJS 13 with the new app directory. I implemented Prisma and connected my MySQL DB then I installed next-auth. The user creation and JWT security all works great but when log in and go to a route that is protected by my middleware exported from the next-auth directory, the browser starts looping an infinite amount of GET requests (see image below) and makes the site irresponsive. It will also return the following error back to me:

> "Failed to fetch RSC payload. Falling back to browser navigation. TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."

#### Note:

Removing the middleware.ts file obviously removes the route protection but it also eliminates the GET loop.

If there is anymore data I can supply to assist please let me know.

### image:

[image: Get requests]

## Code:

### projectDir\app\api\auth[...nextauth]\route.ts

```
// Imports
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import prisma from "@/lib/prisma";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { type NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";

// NextAuth handler.
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    // Set adapter.
    adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
    // Set secret.
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    // Set session strategy.
    session: {
        strategy: 'jwt'
    },
    // Set different login providers.
    providers:[  
        CredentialsProvider({
            // The name to display on the sign in form (e.g. "Sign in with...")
            name: "Credentials",
            // `credentials` is used to generate a form on the sign in page.
            // You can specify which fields should be submitted, by adding keys to the `credentials` object.
            // e.g. domain, username, password, 2FA token, etc.
            // You can pass any HTML attribute to the <input> tag through the object.
            credentials: {
            username: { label: "Email", type: "text", placeholder: "user@email.com" },
            password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
            },
            async authorize(credentials) {
                // Create request to login api
                const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/login", {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        username: credentials?.username,
                        password: credentials?.password,
                    }),
                });

                // Get response from request
                const user = await res.json();
            
                if (res.ok && user) {
                    // If request returns an user, return the user object received.
                    return user
                } else {
                    // If request does not return an user, return null.
                    return null
            
                    // You can also Reject this callback with an Error thus the user will be sent to the error page with the error message as a query parameter
                }
            }
        })
    ],
    callbacks: {
        // Callback for when a jwt is created or updated.
        async jwt({token, user}) {

            return({...token,...user});
        },

        // Callback for when a session is checked.
        async session({session, token}) {
            // Add token to session.
            session.user = token as any;

            return session;
        }
    }
}

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST}
```

### projectDir\middleware.ts

```
export { default } from 'next-auth/middleware'

export const config = {
    matcher: "/settings"
}
```

### projectDir\app\api\login\route.ts

```
// Imports
import { signJwtAccessToken } from "@/lib/jwt";
import prisma from "@/lib/prisma";
import * as bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';

// Interface
interface RequestBody {
    username: string;
    password: string;
}

// Return route.
export async function POST(request: Request) {
    // Get requests body.
    const body: RequestBody = await request.json();

    // Create const with requested user.
    const user = await prisma.user.findFirst({
        where: {
            email: body.username,
        }
    });

    // If user exists check if password is correct and return the user.
    if(user && ( await bcrypt.compare(body.password, user.password))) {
        // Remove password from user object in the response.
        const {password, ...userWithoutPass} = user

        // Create jwt.
        const accessToken = signJwtAccessToken(userWithoutPass);

        // Combine user with jwt as result.
        const result = {
            ...userWithoutPass,
            accessToken,
        }

        // Return the result as JSON object.
        return new Response(JSON.stringify(result));
    }

    // Return null as JSON object.
    else return new Response(JSON.stringify(null));
}
```

### projectDir\app\lib\jwt.ts

```
// Imports
import jwt,{ JwtPayload } from "jsonwebtoken";

// Interfaces
interface SignOption {
    expiresIn?: string | number,
}

// Default token expiration date.
const DEFAULT_SIGN_OPTION:SignOption={
    expiresIn: "1h"
}

// Function to create jwt.
export function signJwtAccessToken(payload: JwtPayload, options: SignOption= DEFAULT_SIGN_OPTION) {
    // Get secret key.
    const secret_key = process.env.SECRET_KEY;

    // Create token.
    const token = jwt.sign(payload, secret_key!, options);

    // Return the token.
    return token;
}

// Function to verify jwt.
export function verifyJwt(token: string) {
    try {
        // Get secret key.
        const secret_key = process.env.SECRET_KEY; 
        // Verify secret key.
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, secret_key!);

        // Return if jwt is valid 
        return decoded as JwtPayload;
    } catch (error) {
        // If jwt is not valid, log the error.
        console.log(error);

        // And return null.
        return null;
    }
}
```

## What I tried

I tried the following with no success. They all resulted in the same problem.

- Different version of different libraries e.g. downgrading next js / downgrading next-auth.
- Removing the custom login route from the route.ts file and using a predefined user.
- Removing callbacks.
- Tried using the middleware on other pages then /settings.
- Reinstalling the node_modules.

Comment: async is known to cause infinite loops https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/51528#issuecomment-1600671255

Comment: @ViktorMS, I read the thread and it states that client components should not be marked as async. None of my components meet those two requirements other then maybe my settings/page.tsx which is marked as async and a child of the root layout which has a client side component that wraps all children in a sessionprovider. But that seems a bit far fetched.

Comment: In my case it was the Supabase Provider instead, and [this helped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76554207/6439240)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the turbopack beta with --turbo in the package.json.